# About array, count, sizeof OR?

Tags: php

I'm triyng to get a count from array like below

```
CASE 1
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => )

CASE 2
Array ( [0] => name [1] => telephone [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => )

If I use COUNT, results is 5
echo count($array);
```

I'm like to get 0 (in case 1) and 2 (in case 2)

Exist a way to do this?

Comment: Filter your array first and remove all values which you want to remove before you count the array or just count the values you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$remove_empty = array_filter($your_array);  
print_r($remove_empty);
```